# Linear Time Hierarchy and Circuit complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, circuit-complexity, polynomial-hierarchy

By Karp-Lipton Theorem we have:
$$PH\subseteq P/poly\Rightarrow PH=\Sigma^p_2$$
So this theorem suggest it is unlikely that $PH\subseteq P/poly$.
I want to know is there any similar conditional or unconditional theorems that study relationship between $LinH$ and $P/poly$?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, PH is the closure of LinH under polytime reductions, hence $LinH\subseteq P/poly$ if and only if $PH\subseteq P/poly$.

Comment: By strengthenings, we also have $\;\;\; NP\subseteq P/poly \: \implies \: PH = S_{\hspace{.02 in}2}\hspace{-0.03 in}P \:\:\:\:$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$